# How to fetch data of songs from out iPhone's iTunes library

Tags: itunes

i want to fetch data of songs from iphone's iTunes library
is it provide any Public API for that ?
or if yes then URL for the API and in which version it support?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure if there is a way, it would be using a private library, and therefore you wouldn't be able to upload your app to the AppStore.